# What chord is E7+(#9)?

Tags: chord-theory, jazz

Came across this on a jazz lead sheet and I have no idea what they meant by the plus. Is it an E7 with an augmented 5th? Is the 7th augmented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really not great way of expressing the following combination of notes:

E G# B# D Fx

In jazz parlance, a + at the end of the chord indicates #5. It is bad practice but it still turns up on lead sheets every once in awhile. I'm pretty sure the real book, for example, still has the turnaround at the end of the bridge of All the Things You Are written as C7+.

There are unfortunately many such old practices that makes reading older lead sheets more challenging than it should be. Another fun one is -10, which is what people would sometimes write before it was agreed that writing 7#9 made a whole lot more sense.

Comment: The + denotes augmented which is one of the 4 basic triad flavors. it's not any differt then seeing a minor chord written like Em7#9 although most would write E+7#9 to denote the plus is for the E and not something else odd.

Comment: The reason that it's bad is that + is also sometimes seen to indicate a major triad, particularly when - is used to denote a minor triad. It's poor form and should be avoided.

Comment: then that's the bad usage and this is the intended usage. not being able to notate a basic triad and calling it a #5 when there is already a term for it is silly. Just like when people call a fully diminished 7th a m6b5 chord or a diminished chord a mb5.

Comment: It's much easier to simply use unambiguous labels for chords, like Aug for a triad and #5 for a 7th chord. + as a notation for augmented is largely obsolete in jazz and I've only ever seen it on old charts; it's simply not regarded as correct anymore and the ambiguity of it is just not needed.

Comment: it's only ambiguous because someone tried to use the + for something else. If someone used m to denote major would we never use it again or # to mean sus? all I'm saying is the argument not to use it doesn't make sense since the + is utilized to mean something specific which is an augmented chord and one misguided use for it somehow throws that concept out the window.

Comment: It's odd--when I was learning jazz, I was told not to use the + but wasn't really given a reason. Perhaps some think it is too similar to chords written like this: "Eadd9"? I could understand avoiding notation where Eadd9 and E+9 mean different things. (Not because of actual ambiguity, as @Dom explains, but because of perceived ambiguity.)

Comment: The reason you shouldn't use it is simply that it's ambiguous and has been assigned more than one meaning historically so it's not worth using. One of the reasons for this, as I previously outlined, is the (still somewhat acceptable) use of a minus sign to depict minor or a flattened note. Augmented is not the opposite of minor, and therefore using a plus sign to depict it has historically caused confusion. This isn't the only problem, however, and it wouldn't surprise me if someone had trouble interpreting how to play a chord written "+7". I know that's 7#5, but why not maj7#5?

Comment: @Fugu it's the same reason why E9 is ambiguous in general you have to know what the symbols mean. nobody would think it's a major 7th based on that symbol. People don't second guess seeing Em9 or EmM9 nor should the second guess E+9 or E+M9. it's the same exact chord formula we know and love. the plus should be less of a monkey wrench then manually altering the chord tones at the end of the symbol which masks function. I understand your argument, but it's extremely silly. People write wrong chord symbols all the time when they do not understanding them.

Comment: old thread, but `+` was used in figured bass to denote a raised interval, so the convention is very old, and IMO very clear.